# How to get OUT of an ISR in freertos / esp-idf

Tags: esp32, freertos, esp-idf

I have an ISR that's fired from a button press. The handler looks like this...

```
void IRAM_ATTR buttonIsrHandler(void *arg) {
  xTaskResumeFromISR(buttonTaskHandle);
}

// `buttonTaskHandle` is set up as the handle for this task function...
void buttonTask(void *pvParameter) {
  while (1) {
    vTaskSuspend(NULL);
    // ... my task code goes here...
  }
}
```

When I'm in an ISR, I can't do certain things. For instance, calling `ESP_LOGI()` results in an error relating to disallowed memory access.

I was expecting those limitations to exist only within the `buttonIsrHandler()` function, but they also exist within `buttonTask()` given that I woke it up from an ISR.

How do I get out of an ISR so that I can do all my normal stuff? I could use something like a queue to do this, but that seems heavy weight. Is there an easier way? Would sending a task-notification from the ISR handler be any different? Any other suggestions?

Comment: The task certainly does not have the restrictions that the ISR does; why do you think that?

Comment: Usually you have to take care about the hardware causing the interrupt to clear the interrupt in the corresponding piece of hardware. Otherwise the ISR will be called over and over again. I’m sure there are many examples how to handle a button/GPIO interrupt correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the documentation of [`xTaskResumeFromISR`](https://www.freertos.org/taskresumefromisr.html), such a use case is not recommended. [Task notifications](https://www.freertos.org/RTOS_Task_Notification_As_Counting_Semaphore.html) are designed and optimized for this exact use case. In your case, you'd want to use [`vTaskNotifyGiveFromISR`](https://www.freertos.org/vTaskNotifyGiveFromISR.html).

As for "leaving the ISR", FreeRTOS will not call your task function from the ISR context. `xTaskResumeFromISR` and other functions simply update the state of the task so that it can run when its turn comes.